# Cutting and pasting using jsPDF results in running out of memory

Tags: javascript, django, memory, blob, jspdf

I have created a Django project called pdfClipper. It allows a user to select clips from an existing PDF file, reorder them in any order they wish, then it creates a new PDF file with those clips pasted in that order.

It begins with opening a PDF file, which is uploaded in the static storage. Then, the user goes through each page, using sliders to get clips. Then, the screen where the user can choose how to reorder clips. Finally, the final screen shows where the new PDF file is created, using a progress bar to show how far along the process is.

The problem is, if there are a lot of clips, the browser potentially runs out of memory.

The following code is from the final page, titled "build.html".

```
// this API gets data about the pdf file being clipped:
// - the file name
// - the maximum page width
// - the maximum page height
async function getFileData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://imcinnes31-pdfclipper.herokuapp.com/pdfclip/api/files?fileId={{fileId}}");
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
}

// this API gets data about each clip wanted from the file:
// - the page where each clip comes from
// - the horizontal and vertical rectangle for each clip (minX, maxX, minY, maxY)
async function getClipData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://imcinnes31-pdfclipper.herokuapp.com/pdfclip/api/clips?fileId={{fileId}}");
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
}

// this API gets data about the order the clips are needed to be pasted in
async function getPosData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://imcinnes31-pdfclipper.herokuapp.com/pdfclip/api/pos?fileId={{fileId}}");
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    (async ()=>{
        const fileData = (await getFileData())[0];
        const clipResult = await getClipData();

        // create dictionary with the clip info
        var clipData = {};
        for (const x in clipResult) {
            clipData[clipResult[x]['clipNumber']] = {};
            clipData[clipResult[x]['clipNumber']]['pageNumber'] = clipResult[x]['pageNumber'];
            clipData[clipResult[x]['clipNumber']]['minY'] = clipResult[x]['minY'];
            clipData[clipResult[x]['clipNumber']]['maxY'] = clipResult[x]['maxY'];
            clipData[clipResult[x]['clipNumber']]['minX'] = clipResult[x]['minX'];
            clipData[clipResult[x]['clipNumber']]['maxX'] = clipResult[x]['maxX'];
        }

        // this shows where on the current page clips are being pasted
        var currentWriteHeight = 0;
        var maxPageHeight = fileData['maxPageHeight'];

        // open file to be cut and pasted, also create new file
        const fileName = '../static/upload/' + fileData['fileName'];
        const pdfRead = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(fileName);

        const hSize = fileData['maxPageWidth'];
        const vSize = maxPageHeight;

        const pdfWrite = new jsPDF({unit: 'px',format: [hSize, vSize]});

        // make array for clip order
        const positionArrayData = await getPosData();
        const positionArray = []
        for (const x in positionArrayData) {
            positionArray.push(positionArrayData[x]['posNumber']);
        }

        // go through each clip in order
        for (const x in positionArray) {

            const currentClip = clipData[positionArray[x]];
            const currentPage = currentClip['pageNumber'];

            // open page to get clip from
            const page = await pdfRead.getPage(currentPage);
            
            // create canvas with the entire page
            const canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
            const viewport = page.getViewport(1);
            canvas1.width = viewport.width;
            canvas1.height = viewport.height;

            // calculate where in the page each rectangle gets clipped from
            const minY = currentClip['minY'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
            const maxY = currentClip['maxY'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
            let minX = 0; 
            let maxX = (page.view[2] - page.view[0]);
            if (currentClip['minX'] != null && currentClip['maxX'] != null) {
                minX = currentClip['minX'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
                maxX = currentClip['maxX'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
            }

            // render the page before clipping
            const rendered = await page.render({
                canvasContext: ctx,
                viewport: viewport
            });

            // reduce the canvas to said rectangle
            const clipImgData = ctx.getImageData(minX, minY, (maxX - minX), (maxY - minY));
            canvas1.width = (maxX - minX);
            canvas1.height = (maxY - minY);
            ctx.putImageData(clipImgData, 0, 0);

            // if the current clip would put it over the current page height, make a new page
            if ((currentWriteHeight + canvas1.height) > vSize) {
                pdfWrite.addPage({format: [hSize, vSize]});
                currentWriteHeight = 0;
            }

            // paste the current clip into the new pdf file
            pdfWrite.addImage(canvas1, 'PNG', 0, currentWriteHeight, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
            currentWriteHeight += canvas1.height;

            canvas1.remove();

            // show the user the progress at which the clips are done

            let pdfProgressPercent = Math.floor(x / positionArray.length * 100);

            document.getElementById('pdfPercent').innerHTML = ('Progress: ' + pdfProgressPercent + '%');
            document.getElementById('pdfProgressBar').style.width = (pdfProgressPercent + '%');

        }
        document.getElementById('pdfPercent').innerHTML = 'Progress: 100%';
        document.getElementById('pdfProgressBar').style.width = '100%';

        // open a new window with the pdf file
        window.open(pdfWrite.output('bloburl'), '_blank');

    })();
});
```

I've noticed when I inspect "Sources" (Chrome is used primarily for this), quite a few blob files are present, one for each page that the clips are taken from.

How do I fix it so this doesn't happen? Is there any way I can clear memory so the browser doesn't run out?

Comment: Consider storing clip data in `LocalStorage` instead of `Heap`.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. It still runs out of memory. However, the clip data is just a dictionary full of numbers as to where to to clip the areas of the pdf.

What about the canvases or the pdf pages or the blob files that are in the "127.0.0.1:8000" directory? Any way to clear the memory from those?